# What does 眉如點倉 mean?

Tags: meaning

> 眉如點倉

眉 - Eyebrow

如 - Like

點 - Dots

倉 - Granary/Sea/etc

So his eyebrows were like ...?

Not too sure what it really means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

点仓 is in Yunan province. It has 19 mountains.
Here is its wiki page [苍山 (大理)](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%8B%8D%E5%B1%B1_%28%E5%A4%A7%E7%90%86%29)

眉如点仓 means the eyebrows are thick, dark, long -- imagine you look at mountains from distance.

I think not lots of mountains can be used to describe eyebrows. 眉如五台，眉如泰山 would look very weird :)

Answer (score 0):

点仓 is a famous mountain。
Chinese traditional literature usually compares female's eyebrows to mountains,
like,眉如远山抹黛，not real mountain，but in the Chinese traditional paintings。
I can't imagine what it looks like too，：）。

Comment: The famous mountain is `点苍`.